# Custom Excel Ribbon Not Showing Up in Customize Ribbon - Excel Professional 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013, ribbon

I need some help here...

I have an Excel file with an custom ribbon. I need to rename that Ribbon, but I can't seem to find it anywhere in Customize Ribbon under Excel Options. However, the ribbon buttons/features show up in Quick Access Toolbar under Excel Options.

I know there is a rename button in Customize Ribbon, but the issue is that it's not showing up there.

Also the tool is not showing up in the Add-Ins Window under options (see image Add-Ins Window).

It might be an Excel Custom Control.

[image: Customize Ribbon Window]
[image: Quick Access Toolbar Window]
[image: PMPP Ribbon Tab]
[image: Add-Ins Window]
[image: Custom Control Indication]

My goal is to rename that ribbon. Let me know if there is any other information that I can provide. Thanks.

Comment: is it 100 percent a custom made ribbon, and not an add in ?

Comment: I did not make it, but I can only think that it's 100% custom. It specifically relates to an activity for this specific sub-department in this specific company. When I look through the VBA for the rest of the tool, there is no indication that it came from anywhere.

Comment: I use a few custom ribbons, and I have never saw any of them not be available in the customize ribbon menu, I do also have a few add ins, these do not show in the customize ribbon menu, that's why I thought it may not actually be a custom ribbon

Comment: I guess it could be an custom add in. I'm not an expert on this.

Comment: If you press Alt+F11 to bring up vba, do you see anything relating to PMPP, a custom ribbon will not have any vba associated with it, and add in probably will do

Comment: Yes there are vba associated with the ribbon. The buttons on the ribbon executes the vba. You're probably right, it's probably an add in. What do I do in that case?

Comment: However, I do not see it in the Add-Ins under Options.

Comment: if it is an add in, you more than likely will not be able to edit it at all

Comment: Thanks for your help PeterH. You really help me work/think through the troubleshooting process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

You just open the workbook in OfficeRibbonXEditor and scroll down to the labels and change the name. See image below.

[OfficeRibbonX Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD5qR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could try exporting the ribbon, as if you were taking it to another computer, then importing it.

**Step 1: Export your customized ribbon:**

1.In the Customize the Ribbon window, click Import/Export.

2.Click Export all customizations.

**Step 2: Import the customized ribbon and Quick Access Toolbar on your other computer**

Important: When you import a ribbon customization file, you lose all prior ribbon and Quick Access Toolbar customizations. If you think that you might want to revert to the customization you currently have, you should export them before importing any new customizations.

1.In the Customize the Ribbon window, click Import/Export.

2.Click Import customization file.

Information and steps taken from:
https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/customize-the-ribbon-in-office-00f24ca7-6021-48d3-9514-a31a460ecb31

**If this does not work, I am going to suggest you either have a bug, or it is not actually a custom ribbon you are trying to find, and rather an add in**

Comment: Still didn't show up after following your steps. Thanks.